# Calculate number of hours filtered by jobNum

Tags: c#, xml, arrays

I'm creating a `string[] array` from an xml file that lists every job number assigned to a time keeping application. I can successfully return string[] from the xml files. I'm trying to match the array for time with the array position for job num and I'm having difficulty. I'm hoping someone here has the paitience to help and/or direct a NEWB to good information already displayed somewhere.

Here is what I have so far. I just can't seem to sew them together. Get Max occurrences of a job number.

```
    public static string totalHoursbyJob()
    {
        int count = 0;

        if (jobNum.Length > count)
        {
            var items = jobNum.Distinct();
            count = items.Count();
            foreach (string value in items)
            {
                string[,] itemArr = new string[count, Convert.ToInt32(jobNum)]; 
            }
        }
    }
```

This gets the time component and calculates the values, but it does not filter by job number. It accurately calculates the values found in the `.innerText` of the nodes in the xml file.

```
        for (i = 0; i < ticks.Length; i++)
        {
            ticksInt = double.Parse(ticks[i]);

            if (ticksInt > 1)
            {
                double small = ((((ticksInt / 10000) / 1000) / 60) / 60);

                sum2 += small;
            }
        }
```

Can somebody please point me to what I'm doing wrong here? Thank you in advance. I really appreciate you stopping by to look and help. :-D Have a Great Day

EDIT1 Cleared an error!! Yay

**EDIT2** Thank you user910683. I removed the code that does nothing at the moment and modified the code that creates the comparative array. Please see next.

```
        if (jobNum.Length > count)
        {
            string[] items = jobNum.Distinct().ToArray();//This change made to clear 
                                                         //error at items.length below

            count = items.Count();
            //itemArr.Join(++items);

            foreach (string value in items)
            {
                string[,] itemArr = new string[count, items.Length];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>     for (jn = 0; jn < jobNum.Length; jn++)
>    {
>        string test = jobNum.ToString();
>    }
> ```

You seem to have a logic error here. You're not using jn within the loop, so each time the loop is executed you're setting test to jobNum.ToString(). You're doing the same thing over and over again, and you're not using the 'test' string for anything. Is this what you want?

Also, consider this line from the previous block:

> string[,] itemArr = new string[count, Convert.ToInt32(jobNum)];

You have removed the exception here by converting jobNum to an Int32, but is this what you want? I would guess that you actually want the number of strings in jobNum, in which case you should use jobNum.Length.

UPDATE
I think I have a better sense of what you want now. Do you want a multidimensional array matching a job number string to the amount of time spent on that job? If so, change:

> ```
>         foreach (string value in items)
>         {
>             string[,] itemArr = new string[count, Convert.ToInt32(jobNum)]; 
>         }
> ```

to something like:

> ```
>         string[,] itemArr = new string[count, 2]; 
>         var items = jobNum.Distinct();
>         for(int x=0; x<items.Count, x++)
>         {
>             itemArr[x][0] = items[x]; 
>         }
>     }
> ```

Then with the ticks, change the ticks conversion from this:

> ```
>            double small = ((((ticksInt / 10000) / 1000) / 60) / 60);
>
>            sum2 += small;
> ```

to something like:

> sum2 += TimeSpan.FromTicks(ticks[i]).TotalHours;

I'd have to see the declaration and initialisation of jobNum and ticks to explain how to put sum2 into your job/time array.

You might consider using something like XmlSerializer instead, it seems like you're doing a lot of manual work with your XML-derived data, you might be able to simplify it for yourself.

Comment: Your first quote should not have been placed by me in the question. I was trying to do something else. My bad. :( I see what you mean about jobNum. In testing jobNum.Length still has a value of [8]. I think I need items.Length but it's throwing an error "Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: jobNum and ticks are not declared in your code so I can only guess what they refer to. I guessed that jobNum.Length would give the number of strings in jobNum, which would be the same as items.Count.

Comment: Again. Thank You. Now I have to figure out how to access values of multi dimensional arrays :-D Thank You very much. If you have any suggestions I would be eternally grateful.